# Pandas how can I extract by regex from column into multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, split

I have the following data:

| ID | content | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2429(sach:MySpezialItem :16.59) | 2022-04-12 |
| 2 | 2429(sach:item 13 :18.59)(sach:this and that costs:16.59) | 2022-06-12 |

And I want to achieve the following:

| ID | number | price | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2429 |  | 2022-04-12 |
| 1 |  | 16.59 | 2022-04-12 |
| 2 | 2429 |  | 2022-06-12 |
| 2 |  | 18.59 | 2022-06-12 |
| 2 |  | 16.59 | 2022-06-12 |

What I tried

```
df['sach'] = df['content'].str.split(r'\(sach:.*\)').explode('content')
df['content'] = df['content'].str.replace(r'\(sach:.*\)','', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single regex with [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
regex = r'(?P<number>\d+)\(|:(?P<price>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)'

df = df.join(df.pop('content').str.extractall(regex).droplevel(1))
```

*NB. if you want a new DataFrame, don't `pop`:*

```
df2 = (df.drop(columns='content')
         .join(df['content'].str.extractall(regex).droplevel(1))
       )
```

output:

```
   ID        date number  price
0   1  2022-04-12   2429    NaN
0   1  2022-04-12    NaN  16.59
1   2  2022-06-12   2429    NaN
1   2  2022-06-12    NaN  18.59
1   2  2022-06-12    NaN  16.59
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vHwLVH/1)

Comment: The content has not always an opening bracket "(" like 2429(sach:MySpezialItem :16.59) sometimes it has just a number like "2429" which ends like this.
Tried to add an | "or" in the regex but failed how can I add this EOL when there is no "(". Thanks already!

Comment: You could maybe match the start of line? `regex = r'(?P<number>^\d+)|:(?P<price>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)'`

Comment: Not quite yet. There also some more problems.[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/c0kc53/1) The beginning can be alpha nummeric, also there dont have to be anything before an opening bracket "(". Not getting less tricky ..

Comment: Then I suggest you open a regex question with all the details ;)

Comment: Your right but im very close ! `(?P<number>^\w+)|:(?P<price>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)`  The 
made an impact ! \w+. Only thing is left is between number "." or ",".

Comment: `(?P<number>^\w+)|:(?P<price>\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\)`?

Comment: haha, thanks (I'm going to get it right now!) and happy coding ;)